# Get visible view at certain point

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview

I have a point CGPoint in coordinates of the application window.
Is there a way to get a pointer to the view visible at that point?

E.g. I have 100 views or random sizes and placed at random locations - some partially/fully covering each other. 
Pressing a button in the app will list the address of the view visible at (0,0), (100,100) and at (200,200).
The views may or may not have userInteraction enabled.
Also, what about the more complicated scenario where a view is covered by a fully transparent view?

Answer (score 7):

**Updated**
`hitTest` will not work as it will not give you subtrees where a parent has `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO` or a view which is outside of its parent's bounds.

`visibleViewAtPoint` as described below will parse the entire view tree and give the view with the highest subview index. This should give the correct view (does not take z-order into consideration...)

```
- (void) findView:(UIView**)visibleView atPoint:(CGPoint)pt fromParent:(UIView*)parentView
{
    UIView *applicationWindowView = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] view];

    if(parentView == nil) {
        parentView = applicationWindowView;
    }

    for(UIView *view in parentView.subviews) 
    {        
        if((view.superview != nil) && (view.hidden == NO) && (view.alpha > 0)) 
        {
            CGPoint pointInView = [applicationWindowView convertPoint:pt toView:view];

            if([view pointInside:pointInView withEvent:nil]) {
                *visibleView = view;
            }

            [self findView:visibleView atPoint:pt fromParent:view];
        }
    }
}

- (UIView*) visibleViewAtPoint:(CGPoint)pt
{
    UIView *visibleView = nil;
    [self findView:&visibleView atPoint:pt fromParent:nil];

    return visibleView;
}
```

Comment: At present this code doesn't detect a UIAlertView, or other 'popup' views such as the UIPickerView that's presented after tapping a drop-down list in a UIWebView. Is that something that this code could be modified to do, or do these fall under the 'view which is outside of its parent's bounds' case? If the latter, how else can you detect and retrieve such views?

Comment: A UIAlertView maintains it's own UIScreen, which would be outside of your view controllers view, so this method wouldn't work for that. You'd probably need to track down the UIAlertView's screen (somehow) and perform this method there.